# Does Craft have a bookmarklet to quickly post/save content from the web?

Tags: plugins

Does Craft have a bookmarklet that allows you to quickly post images, text, videos or any other content from web pages to Craft entry types/fields?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing from P&T and I haven't seen one floating around the web, either.